# Where do I put static files in my React.JS app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I ran `create-react-app` and I got the usual structure with `public`, `src` and the javascript files. All fine.

Now I want to add Bootstrap3 to this, but I want to add the normal css/js/font folders instead and create my own components that uses Bootstrap.

The question is; where do I put the files?
Inside the `public` folder, or in the `src`?

And I assume I simply refer to them the normal way by adding the `<script>` and the `<link>` tags in the `public/index.html`?

Thanks.

Comment: If the app is connected over internet (not just intranet), using CDN libraries would be better than storing the libraries locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from create-react-app documentation.

> Inside index.html, you can use it like this:
>
> ```
> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
> ```
>
> Only files inside the public folder will be accessible by %PUBLIC_URL% prefix

So, you can add your css inside the public folder, and then add it using  tag with the url prefix with %PUBLIC_URL%

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using React-Bootstrap instead. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/introduction.html

Comment: I did at first, but it's not good enough for my customization needs. And it still feels quite immature.  Hence the need for "adding it the old fashioned" way and then create my own components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap by adding cdn link in head tag in index.html